# Create odd-numbered answers, or all answers

Tags: conditionals, answers

I'm starting with a clean slate creating a solutions manual. I would like the ability, by setting a switch, to produce only the solutions for the odd-numbered problems, or those for all problems, in each section.

I would much prefer not to use one of the answer packages, as I've not had great success with those in the past. My preferred solution would be to modify the itemized list macros in such a way that they would produce no output in particular cases. Or is there another, better way?

I should add that exercises will be numbered chapter.section.#, and it is whether # is even or odd that should govern inclusion.

I would imagine that I've not provided enough information for a decent answer, but I'm not sure what else to say...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following shows a proof-of-concept that may be something you're looking for.

Packages used include

- [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem): For advanced manipulation of lists; and
- [`environ`](http://ctan.org/pkg/environ): To allow for possible lengthy answers that may include paragraphs.

A boolean `oddonly` is used to condition on whether to print only odd-numbered answers or not. This is set to either `true` or `false` using `\oddonly<bool>` (where `<bool>` is either `true` or `false`). Two counters are used to number questions and answers, respectively. The reason for defining environments (`question` and `answer`) is, as mentioned above, because you might want to include a large description in a question/answer, for which the `environ` package is useful.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\usepackage{environ}% http://ctan.org/pkg/environ
\begin{document}

\newif\ifoddonly% Boolean to print odd-only answers
\oddonlytrue% Odd only answers = TRUE
\newcounter{question}[section]% Question counter (within section)
\newcounter{answer}[section]% Answer counter (within section)

\NewEnviron{question}{\stepcounter{question}\item \BODY}% Question
\NewEnviron{answer}{% Answer
  \stepcounter{answer}%
  \ifodd\value{answer}% Condition on value of answer
    \item \BODY% Print odd answer
  \else\ifoddonly\else
      \item \BODY% Print even answer
  \fi\fi%
}

% QUESTIONS ===========

\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Questions} \label{questions}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{question})]
  \begin{question} Here is a question? \end{question}
  \begin{question} Here is another question? \end{question}
  \begin{question} This is yet another question? \end{question}
  \begin{question} Oh, and another one? \end{question}
  \begin{question} Here's the final question? \end{question}
\end{enumerate}

% ANSWERS =============

\section{Answers to Section~\ref{questions}}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\ref{questions}.\arabic{answer})]
  \begin{answer} Answer to this question. \end{answer}
  \begin{answer} Answer to that question. \end{answer}
  \begin{answer} Answer to another question. \end{answer}
  \begin{answer} Answer to fourth question. \end{answer}
  \begin{answer} Final answer. \end{answer}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Odd-answers only]

Setting `\oddonlyfalse` (the default) in the above example yields:

[image: All answers]

You may want to play around with the alignment of your list labels. However, for this, I suggest viewing some of alignment possibilities in the [`enumitem` package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf).

Comment: That answer is helpful on so many levels I don't know where to start. Thanks so much.

Comment: What happen if if we do `\renewcommand\theanswer{\Roman{answer}}` and then `\isodd{\theanswers}`, or something like that? I think is better use `\isodd{\value{answer}}`.

Answer (score 4):

I know that you don't want a solution using the `answers` package, but for anyone interested I have put one below, which is a stripped-down version of what I have used for this task.

You can show/hide the odd (or even, or both) numbered solutions using these switches, set to 1 (show), or 0 (hide):

```
\setcounter{showodd}{1}
\setcounter{showeven}{1}
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{ifthen}                        % conditionals
\usepackage{answers}                       % solutions to problems
\usepackage{xstring}                       % used to determine if problems are odd or even

% question environment 
\newcounter{question}
\setcounter{question}{0}
\renewcommand{\thequestion}{\thesection.\arabic{question}}
\newenvironment{question}{\refstepcounter{question}\thequestion.}{}

% open the solutions file
\Opensolutionfile{shortsolutions}
\Newassociation{shortsolution}{shortSoln}{shortsolutions}

\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Questions}

\begin{question}
Here's  a question.
\begin{shortsolution}
First answer.
\end{shortsolution}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Another question.
\begin{shortsolution}
Second answer.
\end{shortsolution}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Here's  a question.
\begin{shortsolution}
Third answer.
\end{shortsolution}
\end{question}

\begin{question}
Another question.
\begin{shortsolution}
Fourth answer.
\end{shortsolution}
\end{question}


% close the solutions files
\Closesolutionfile{shortsolutions}

% set up switches to show odd or even problems
%   1: show
%   0: don't show (actually, anything other than 1 makes it not show)
\newcounter{showodd}
\newcounter{showeven}
\setcounter{showodd}{1}
\setcounter{showeven}{1}

% solution to problem (show only odd, even, all)
% Note: this renewenvironment needs to go here
%       so that the answers package can still
%       display correctly to the page if needed
\newcounter{oddproblemnumber}
\renewenvironment{shortSoln}[1]{%
    % before the environment starts
    \fullexpandarg % need this line so that '.' are counted
        % numbers such as 1.3.1, 1.2.4, 7.5.6
        \StrBehind{#1}{.}[\newbit]%
        \StrBehind{\newbit}{.}[\problemnumber]%
     % determine if the problem number is odd or even
     % and depending on our choices above, display or not
     \ifthenelse{\isodd{\problemnumber}}%
     {%
         % set a counter that says the problem number is odd (used later)
         \setcounter{oddproblemnumber}{1}%
         % display or not 
         \ifthenelse{\theshowodd=1}
         {%
            % if we want to show the odd problems
            {\par\bfseries #1.}%
         }%
         {%
            % otherwise don't show them!
            \expandafter\comment%          
         }%
     }%
     {%
         % even numbered problem, set the counter (used later)
         \setcounter{oddproblemnumber}{0}%
         \ifthenelse{\theshoweven=1}
         {%
            % if we want to show the even problems
            {\par\itshape #1.}%
         }%
         {%
            % otherwise don't show them!
            \expandafter\comment%          
         }%
     }%
}%
{%
    % after the environment finishes
    \ifthenelse{\theoddproblemnumber=1}%
    {%
        % odd numbered problems 
         \ifthenelse{\theshowodd=1}
         {%
            % if we want to show the odd problems
            % then the environment is finished
         }%
         {%
            % otherwise we need to finish the comment
            \expandafter\endcomment%
         }%
    }%
    {%
        % even numbered problems
         \ifthenelse{\theshoweven=1}
         {%
            % if we want to show the even problems
            % then the environment is finished
         }%
         {%
            % otherwise we need to finish the comment
            \expandafter\endcomment%
         }%
    }%
}


\newpage
\section{Answers}
\IfFileExists{shortsolutions.tex}{\input{shortsolutions.tex}}{}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. My issue with the answers package is the amount of file infrastructure that it needs. It seems really bulky to use, although I imagine that if I just used it I'd get used to it. It simply seems to more than I need, and thus is harder to use than I'd like.

Comment: I used to think that too, but am now pretty much in love with the `answers` package. It allows me to move questions around without worrying about the order- if I used the `enumerate` solution then I don't think the same would be true as I would have to adjust the ordering of the answers manually.

Answer (score 1):

I'dont know if this helps you, but my approach for conditional document creating is using the *versions* package. With this package, you can include selected regions this way:

```
\begin{VERSIONfinal}
This text will only appear if VERSIONfinal is included
\end{VERSIONfinal}
```

Somewhere after `\begin{document}` you have either to include or exclude a particular Version with `\includeversion{VERSIONfinal}` or `\excludeversion{VERSIONfinal}`.

Note: There is also a *version* package, so far I did not use it.