# Through enumeration

Tags: numbering, environments

I would like to have problems be consecutively numbered throughout a book, irrespective of the chapters and sections where they appear.

E.g.

```
Chapter 1
[Text]
1. Some problem
Section 1
2. Some problem
[Text]
Section 2
3. Some problem
Etc
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Assuming you will want to typeset solutions as well, you can combine @Werner's solution with code from the `answers` package: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/answers

Comment: Also of interest (without the "[counter within](http://texblog.net/help/latex/ltx-271.html)" part), might be: [Create odd-numbered answers, or all answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26601/create-odd-numbered-answers-or-all-answers/26607#26607)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make your own environment that works on a counter. It allows you freedom to manage the formatting of the problem typesetting as well. Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\newcounter{problem}
\newenvironment{problem}{%
  \refstepcounter{problem}% For correct referencing
  \textbf{Problem~\theproblem.}\ 
}{\par}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter} \lipsum[1]
\section{first section} \lipsum[2]
\begin{problem}
Here is a very interesting problem that you can do. \label{problem1}
\end{problem}
\lipsum[3]
\section{Second section} \lipsum[4]
\begin{problem}
Wow, have you seen this problem? \label{problem2}
\end{problem}
\section{Last section} \lipsum[5]
\begin{problem}
This is the final problem of the book. It is actually much harder than
Problems~\ref{problem1} and~\ref{problem2} combined.
\end{problem}
\lipsum[7]

\end{document}
```

The [`lipsum` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provides dummy text used to fill the "book". In the above example, the problem is typeset as a paragraph in the form:

> **Problem 1.** blah blah blah
>
> ...
>
> **Problem 2.** blah blah blah
>
> ...

Since the counter is not tied to any other counter, it runs through the book without resetting. Referencing is also possible using labels in the traditional way.

[image: Problems]

Answer (score 3):

A lot depends on how you are defining the problem environment.  If you are creating your own environment, then define the relevant counter to not depend on anything.

If your problem environment is being created by, e.g. on of the theorem packages (such as `amsthm`) you can usually specify the relations among the counters when you define the theorem type.

Finally, if you are using a package that defines its own problem environment that automatically determines the counter dependencies, you can use the [`chngcntr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chgcntr) package  to easily control the numbering relations among existing counters.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `enumitem` package with which you can easily resume a list.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcounter{ProblemNumber}%
\newenvironment{Problem}{%
    \begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumi}{\theProblemNumber}
}{%
   \setcounter{ProblemNumber}{\value{enumi}}
   \end{enumerate}
}%

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
Text
\begin{Problem}
  \item Some Problem
\end{Problem}
\section{Section One}
Some Text
\begin{Problem}
  \item Some Problem
\end{Problem}
\section{Section Two}
\begin{Problem}
  \item Some Problem
\end{Problem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This isn't an ideal way to do things, since you may need other enumerations in the document.  It's better to have a specific problem environment.

Comment: Duh!!! Thanks Alan. I have adapted the previous solution so that you can still use other enumerations which won't effect this list.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least three packages -- `theorem`, `ntheorem`, and `amsthm` -- that can create numbered environments with various styles for the fonts of the headers and the body of the environment, various amounts of vertical skip before and after the environment, etc. While these packages were originally created for writers who need environments for theorems, corollaries, and the like, their code is really applicable to a wide range of situations. The MWE below uses the `ntheorem` package. Happy TeXing!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ntheorem,lipsum}
\theorembodyfont{\slshape}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{problem}[Apollo 13]\label{prob:houston}
Houston, we have a problem.
\end{problem}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Next section}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{problem}[Cool Terminator] \label{prob:term}
No problemo.
\end{problem}
\section{Still another section}
As might be noted from Problems \ref{prob:houston} 
and \ref{prob:term}, \ldots
\end{document}
```